# Display itemcode, supplier name and total quantity for the ordered items, whose total quantity ordered is greater than or equal to 100

Tags: sql

Display itemcode, supplier name and total quantity for the ordered items, whose total quantity ordered is greater than or equal to 100.

tables are:

Quotation(QuotationId,Sname,ItemCode,QuotedPrice,QDate,QStatus)

Orders(OrderId,QuotationId,QtyOrdered,OrderDtae)

```
select  Q.itemcode ,Q.sname, O.QtyOrdered as TOTALQUANTITY 
from Quotation Q
    inner join Orders O on Q.QuotationId = O.QuotationId
where QtyOrdered >= 100
```

Query Result :

```
ITEMCODE  SNAME           TOTALQUANTITY
I1008     EBATs               100
I1009     VV Electronics      100
I1009     VV Electronics      150
```

expected result :

```
TEMCODE  SNAME            TOTALQUANTITY
I1009    VV Electronics      250
I1008    EBATs               150
```

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY`, and `SUM()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get expected results with following:

```
select  Q.itemcode ,Q.sname, SUM(O.QtyOrdered) as TOTALQUANTITY 
from Quotation Q
    inner join Orders O on (Q.QuotationId = O.QuotationId
and O.QtyOrdered >= 100) GROUP BY Q.itemcode, Q.sname
```

Comment: It says   "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: thanks for helping just needed to add Q.sname in group by

Comment: Updated answer, its due to full group by mode.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Q.ITEMCODE,Q.SNAME, SUM(O.QTYORDERED) TOTALQUANTITY 
FROM QUOTATION Q
    INNER JOIN ORDERS O ON Q.QUOTATIONID= O.QUOTATIONID
 GROUP BY Q.ITEMCODE, Q.SNAME HAVING SUM(O.QTYORDERED)>=100
```

Comment: It's usually good to give a bit of context with the code - what you've changed, why etc

Comment: While it is appropriate to have upper-case SQL keywords and even is considered a good formatting practice, please note that upper-case table and column names may result in fail under certain conditions (depending on OS and RDBMS configuration). So it's better to use the case that OP has provided.